# MVC 5 Omit certain data when using editorFor

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to pull information from a database. currently it should pull two things:

Approved, 
Admin

I want the user to see and changed the Approved checkbox but not the Admin checkbox. The only problem being that it needs to stay dynamic because more things will be added later. Is there a way to Omit the Admin checkbox?

Thanks

edit:
I should add that it pulls from the database properly and does what it should, but I don't want it to show the admin checkbox

Comment: Can  you post some code and what you've tried to far?

Comment: The first thing that we tried was 
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Roles)
The second thing we tried was basically the same but wrapping it in a foreach statement.
I have done research and I know how to completely omit a table from the database. However nothing seems to have information with regards to completely skipping specific information.

Comment: Posting some code should help as it's not clear what you are asking